Compile two times with boolean set to true first and then false
I just received some tex files where there is a boolean defined at the beginning of the document with the etoolbox package. Changing the boolean produces a slightly different pdf. To produce the other version of the document, I have to copy the first pdf to not overwrite it when compiling again, change the boolean and then compile a second time. Is there a way to compile the document two times with the boolean set to the both true and false separately and and receive two pdfs?
Thank you very much!

Welcome to TeX.SE!

https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=583 might be helpful

As Ronnie Marksch mentions, any one call to tex can only produce one pdf.  There are various approaches, but at some point they all run tex twice.

In my environment I have something similar, which is why I use two .tex files, one like
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,DIV12,BCOR1.5cm]{scrbook}
%
\osversiontrue
\input{main.tex}

and one like
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,DIV12,BCOR1.5cm]{scrbook}
%
\input{main.tex}

and a main.tex that contains all the rest, everything starting with \begin{document} and ending with \end{document}.
When I compile both wrapper files, two pdf documents are created.
The differences between the two documents are addressed by the boolean osversion.

Ok, that's smart, I will try that. However, you still have to compile two times.

well, it's only a single Makefile. One make builds both documents

See also here how to pass args to the tex file. It is just a different solution.
However, you have to compile twice since one call to pdflatex/.. will create a single PDF only.
Creating both versions in one go resulting in one PDF and splitting that PDF in the 'middle' probably is not more convenient.
Last option I can think of, check for the existence of a file to determine the boolean and create/delete that file between the two pdflatex runs.
